# Angular UI Bootstrap Carousel. Not able to remove slides only addSlide option is there

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here goes my angular-bootstrap-ui carousel code:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.myInterval = 5000;
  $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
  var slides = $scope.slides = [];
  $scope.addSlide = function() {
    var newWidth = 600 + slides.length + 1;
    slides.push({
      image: '//placekitten.com/' + newWidth + '/300',
      text: ['More','Extra','Lots of','Surplus'][slides.length % 4] + ' ' +
        ['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][slides.length % 4]
    });
  };
  for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    $scope.addSlide();
  }
});
```

and carousel is getting populated somewher

```
<carousel interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
  <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
      <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
    </div>
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

I want to refresh the slides after specific event. meaning removing all slides and replacing with entirely new set.

When i try to clear slides like this

```
slides = $scope.slides = [];
```

after specific click event. and try addSlide again.

```
for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    $scope.addSlide();
  }
```

carousel is not appearing now at all.

Need Help!

Comment: Seems working. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/fqbuv65s/). Maybe it is a version issue, you can try to use the lastest version of angular and ui.bootstrap or change my fiddle for your case.

Comment: Thanks! @themyth92 version is the issue.